# Wired connection isn't connecting to internet

Tags: networking

I have a PC computer installed with Ubuntu 12.4.4 (no other OS) that is wired directly to the router. Router (AE1000) and modem working, have a laptop running Ubuntu and is connected to router through a wire and working flawlessly.

The PC is a 1 terabyte machine with more then 10gig of RAM the wired connection is set to Auto on IPV4 and IPV6. The network port on the machine (ethernet) is directly built into the motherboard (it is not a separate card) SIS900. Ubuntu is getting all network information automatically but when I run checks there are two different error messages "Destination Host Unreachable" and something about the not being on the Network.

All the information on the GUI side is correct. The installation on this machine has been particularly difficult and I have spent several days in overcoming many problems faced. The system is working great expect for this one caveat. Step by step works best for me, this way I can be methodical in my approach.

Answer (score 0):

However, I don't understand why that should happen only after you use static-IP -- maybe your interface was configured down initially. 
If your router IP is 192.168.1.1 it is very likely to be a Class-B subnet configuration.
This means the netmask would be 255.255.0.0.
By using a Class-C netmask and a network number of 192.168.1.0, you have placed your PC in a different subnet from your router.  That would explain the ping unreachable case.
Show me your interface ip?